# Setting null to foreign key column during save operation in jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have a Child entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    private UUID uuid;

    private String str1;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
    ....
}
```

and parent entity as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {
    @Id
    private String bId;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to save a null value in the foreign key column "b_id" in table A when a save operation is performed. Can I do that using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add nullable = true and also optional = true. Optional is often forgotten.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = true)
private B b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, `@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = true)` default value of nullable is `true` so your FK column can store `null` without setting any value of `nullable`.

Table A is referring to B, so Parent is B, not A.

Comment: Thanks Darshana. However when I try to add the object of A to the database I get an primary key constraint exception from b_id

Comment: Could you please Attached your code to save A table and error message with question.